# AngularJS multi-element directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

AngularJS supports multi-element directive with `-start` and `-end` postfix. The official documentation only mentions `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. Do other built-in directives support this?

For example, this works fine:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-controller="myController">
    <td>{{firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{lastName}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Both `{{firstName}}` and `{{lastName}}` are replaced with their proper value.

But this only works partially:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-controller-start="myController">
    <td>{{firstName}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-controller-end>
    <td>{{lastName}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

`{{firstName}}` is properly replaced. But `{{lastName}}` is empty.
Since `{{firstName}}` works, seems `ng-controller-start` is recognized by AngularJS. Is it a bug, or I'm doing it wrong, that `{{lastName}}` is not working?

**Update**
If `ng-controller-start` and `ng-controller-end` is not officially supported. How do I make `ng-controller` to span multiple elements? Can I use comment-style directive? If yes, how?

Comment: Pretty sure that this is unique to `ng-repeat`: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I think it may be half-baked feature for other directives. When I remove `ng-controller-end`, AngularJS throws an exception saying "no matching ng-controller-end found for ng-controller-start", so it definitely understands `ng-controller-start`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills [That's not](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e8066c4b4ce11496b0d8f39e41b4d753048bca2d), but using it with `ngController` is kinda strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not a directive supports this is based on its directive definition and the [`multiElement`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-multielement-) property.

It doesn't seem like Angular's documentation says which built in directives are multi-element, but [a Github search](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=multielement%3A&type=Code) seems to reveal that it's only `ngRepeat`, `ngSwitchWhen`, `ngSwitchDefault`, `ngIf`, `ngShow`, and `ngHide`.

You can create your own directives with `multiElement` as well.

Answer (score 4):

### In Angular 1.2

With Angular 1.2, support for multi-element directives was introduced. It seems like the specific use-case they had in mind was ngRepeat, since it wasn't promoted to be used with any of the other built-in directives as far as I am aware. With ngRepeat, however, it solved a very particular problem such as how to repeat more than one table row per item.

In 1.2, the `$compile` service will detect *any* directive that is suffixed with `-start` and assume it to be one of a pair of multi-element directive attributes ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.25/src/ng/compile.js#L1038)). This leads to the undesirable side-effect that you cannot name your directive `something-start`, as the `$compile` service will get confused when it does not find the multi-element counterpart.

This leads to the error: `Error: [$compile:uterdir] Unterminated attribute, found 'something-start' but no matching 'something-end' found.`

The fact that the `$compile` service is indiscriminate in treating directives as multi-element is why you are able to use `ng-controller-start` and `ng-controller-end` in Angular 1.2. However the ngController directive is not designed to deal with multiple elements and this is why it does not work as expected. It will act on the first element in the range, and ignore the rest - just as you observed.

### In Angular 1.3

Angular 1.3 fixes the above problem by requiring that any multi-element directives be explicitly defined as such by using the new `multiElement: true` property on the directive definition object. [See the docs on this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-multielement-)

This means that `ng-controller-start` will not do *anything* in 1.3, since it will cause the compiler to look for a directive named "ngControllerStart", which does not exist. Therefore the directive attribute will simply be ignored.

As the other answer points out, you can now search the angular.js GitHub repo for "multiElement" to see the specific core directives that support this feature.